# OpenCV enum variables(like CV_BGR2GRAY or CV_AA) missing in the recent Java API?

Tags: java, api, opencv, enums, computer-vision

I've setup a Java project in Eclipse to detect faces and eyes in images.
Everything is working fine except that I'm forced to use numeric values to represent the enum variables like `CV_BGR2GRAY` or `CV_AA`.
Is there some import(or there is a way to reference them) that can be done to access them?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`CV_BGR2GRAY` should be defined as `Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY`, and `CV_AA` as `Core.LINE_AA`.

Comment: WILL SOMEONE PLEASE UPDATE THE OPENCV DOCUMENTATION ACCORDINGLY! It's been a year!

Comment: `CV_AA` => `cv::LINE_AA` in OpenCV 4.